# Cypher : Top N members of a group with ex-aequo

Tags: neo4j, limit, cypher

I have a set of documents , each belonging to 1 or several groups.

Persons can recommend these documents

I need for each group the documents that have position 1 to N in terms of number of received recommendations, meaning that when this is an intermediary result and N=3

```
Document   Recommendations
a          7 
b          4
c          4
d          3
```

it would return the a,b and c

With this:

```
Document   Recommendations
a          6 
b          5
c          4
d          4
```

it would return the a,b,c and d

and with this

With this:

```
Document   Recommendations
a          6 
b          4
c          4
d          4
e          3
```

it would return a,b,c,and d

How do I do this kind of stuff in Cypher? I've gotten this far (was planning to put a link to the console but it doesn't seem to work)

```
//Groups
create (gr1:Group {name:"First group"})
create (gr2:Group {name:"Second group"})

//Persons
create (p1:Person {name:"Jan"})
create (p2:Person {name:"Marie"})
create (p3:Person {name:"Willem"})
create (p4:Person {name:"Simone"})
create (p5:Person {name:"Henk"})
create (p6:Person {name:"Ilse"})
create (p7:Person {name:"Tom"})
create (p8:Person {name:"Detlef"})

//Content
create (ci1:Contentitem { title: "Sometitle 1"})
create (ci2:Contentitem { title: "Sometitle 2"})
create (ci3:Contentitem { title: "Sometitle 3"})
create (ci4:Contentitem { title: "Sometitle 4"})
create (ci5:Contentitem { title: "Sometitle 5"})
create (ci6:Contentitem { title: "Sometitle 6"})
create (ci7:Contentitem { title: "Sometitle 7"})
create (ci8:Contentitem { title: "Sometitle 8"})
create (ci9:Contentitem { title: "Sometitle 9"})
create (ci10:Contentitem { title: "Sometitle 10"})

//Recommendations
create (ci1)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p4)
create (ci8)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p8)
create (ci1)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p1)
create (ci8)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p7)
create (ci5)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p6)
create (ci1)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p3)
create (ci8)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p3)
create (ci5)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p4)
create (ci8)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p5)
create (ci5)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p2)
create (ci5)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p1)
create (ci5)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p8)
create (ci2)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p1)
create (ci2)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p3)
create (ci2)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p7)
create (ci10)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p8)
create (ci3)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p4)
create (ci10)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p5)
create (ci3)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p1)
create (ci4)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p5)
create (ci4)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p8)
create (ci6)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p5)
create (ci9)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p1)
create (ci9)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p2)
create (ci6)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p6)
create (ci6)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p8)

//Group membership
create (ci1)-[:BelongsToGroup]->(gr1)
create (ci1)-[:BelongsToGroup]->(gr2)
create (ci2)-[:BelongsToGroup]->(gr1)
create (ci3)-[:BelongsToGroup]->(gr1)
create (ci4)-[:BelongsToGroup]->(gr1)
create (ci4)-[:BelongsToGroup]->(gr2)
create (ci5)-[:BelongsToGroup]->(gr1)
create (ci6)-[:BelongsToGroup]->(gr1)
create (ci7)-[:BelongsToGroup]->(gr1)
create (ci8)-[:BelongsToGroup]->(gr1)
create (ci8)-[:BelongsToGroup]->(gr2)
create (ci10)-[:BelongsToGroup]->(gr1)
create (ci10)-[:BelongsToGroup]->(gr2)
;
```

and the query

```
match (gr)<-[:BelongsToGroup]-(ci:Contentitem)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p:Person)
return gr.name,ci.title,count(p) as Recommendations 
order by gr.name, Recommendations desc
```

which returns

```
gr.name          ci.title           Recommendations
----------------------------------------------------
First group      Sometitle 5        5
First group      Sometitle 8        4
First group      Sometitle 1        3
First group      Sometitle 6        3
First group      Sometitle 2        3
First group      Sometitle 4        2
First group      Sometitle 3        2
First group      Sometitle 10       2
Second group     Sometitle 8        4
Second group     Sometitle 1        3
Second group     Sometitle 10       2
Second group     Sometitle 4        2
```

with N=3, the final result should be

```
gr.name          ci.title           Recommendations
----------------------------------------------------
First group      Sometitle 5        5
First group      Sometitle 8        4
First group      Sometitle 1        3
First group      Sometitle 6        3
First group      Sometitle 2        3
Second group     Sometitle 8        4
Second group     Sometitle 1        3
Second group     Sometitle 10       2
Second group     Sometitle 4        2
```

with N=2, the final result would be

```
gr.name          ci.title           Recommendations
----------------------------------------------------
First group      Sometitle 5        5
First group      Sometitle 8        4
Second group     Sometitle 8        4
Second group     Sometitle 1        3
```

What is important in the ex-aequo rule is that the group with the lowest number of recommendations that starts at a position <=N , is not cut off at an arbitrairy position, but fully included. So, when we have the case before cutoff like this

```
gr.name          ci.title           Recommendations
----------------------------------------------------
First group      Sometitle 5        5
First group      Sometitle 8        4
First group      Sometitle 1        4
First group      Sometitle 6        3
First group      Sometitle 2        3
First group      Sometitle 4        2
First group      Sometitle 3        2
First group      Sometitle 10       2
Second group     Sometitle 8        4
Second group     Sometitle 1        4
Second group     Sometitle 10       2
Second group     Sometitle 4        2
Second group     Sometitle 7        1
```

the end result for N=3 would be:

```
gr.name          ci.title           Recommendations
----------------------------------------------------
First group      Sometitle 5        5
First group      Sometitle 8        4
First group      Sometitle 1        4
Second group     Sometitle 8        4
Second group     Sometitle 1        4
Second group     Sometitle 10       2
Second group     Sometitle 4        2
```

and for N=2

```
gr.name          ci.title           Recommendations
----------------------------------------------------
First group      Sometitle 5        5
First group      Sometitle 8        4
First group      Sometitle 1        4
Second group     Sometitle 8        4
Second group     Sometitle 1        4
```

Comment: can you give another example for N=2 or something? The N=3 giving the final result isn't making sense to me.

Comment: I think I figured it out.

Comment: for N=2, I only adapted the coalesce to
with gr, coalesce(cutoffs[1], cutoffs[0]) as cutoff
and it worked fine. 

But there is a catch. When the first 3 titles have the same number of recommendations and the rest has less. there's still case that's not covered .. Will add an example

Comment: maybe try without distinct in the collect.

Comment: added stuff to improve explanation of cutoff rule

Comment: I added that thinking you'd want the top 3 distinct, but if you want to count them as separate then you want not distinct.

Comment: you're right. Great solution with the coalesce(cutoffs[]..)  thanks, lots of fields of application of this technique.

Comment: solution in console can be found here http://console.neo4j.org/?id=gn95q7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a clean way to do exactly what you want, but here's my best try. It requires a second match after you figure out the cutoff.

Something like this:

```
match (gr)<-[:BelongsToGroup]-(ci:Contentitem)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p:Person)
with gr, ci, count(p) as recommendations
order by recommendations desc
with gr, collect(recommendations) as cutoffs
// coalesce here to avoid null problems if you don't have N=3 distinct recommendations
with gr, coalesce(cutoffs[2], cutoffs[1], cutoffs[0]) as cutoff
match (gr)<-[:BelongsToGroup]-(ci:Contentitem)-[:IsRecommendedBy]->(p:Person)
with gr, ci, count(p) as recommendations, cutoff
where recommendations >= cutoff
return gr.name, ci.title, recommendations, cutoff
order by gr.name, recommendations desc;
```

gives:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| gr.name        | ci.title       | recommendations | cutoff |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| "First group"  | "Sometitle 5"  | 5               | 3      |
| "First group"  | "Sometitle 8"  | 4               | 3      |
| "First group"  | "Sometitle 1"  | 3               | 3      |
| "First group"  | "Sometitle 6"  | 3               | 3      |
| "First group"  | "Sometitle 2"  | 3               | 3      |
| "Second group" | "Sometitle 8"  | 4               | 2      |
| "Second group" | "Sometitle 1"  | 3               | 2      |
| "Second group" | "Sometitle 4"  | 2               | 2      |
| "Second group" | "Sometitle 10" | 2               | 2      |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
9 rows
```

update: It occurred to me that you'd probably want to pass in `N` instead of have it coded like this with coalesce. In that case, you could do:

```
with gr, reduce(acc=cutoffs[0], x in range(0, {N}-1)| coalesce(cutoffs[x], acc)) as cutoff
```

This will go through the range 0 to N-1 without the need to hard code it like the first solution.

Comment: added a slightly more parameter friendly version.

Answer (score 2):

You got a good answer already (+1) but I was curious if it could be done without the second match. Here's what I came up with

```
MATCH (gr)<-[:BelongsToGroup]-(ci:Contentitem)-[r:IsRecommendedBy]->() // I dropped (p:Person) since it's not really relevant, and counted the [:IsRecommendedBy] instead
WITH gr, [ci, count(r)] AS document
ORDER BY document[1] desc
WITH gr, collect(document) as documents, collect(document[1]) as recommendations
WITH gr, documents, recommendations, 
    CASE WHEN length(recommendations) >= {n} THEN {n}-1 ELSE length(recommendations)-1 END as ix
RETURN gr.name AS group,[doc IN documents 
    WHERE doc[1]>= recommendations[ix]| [(doc[0]).title, doc[1]]] AS documents
```

I don't know if this is necessarily any better, but it's different, with one match, `CASE WHEN` instead of `REDUCE/COALESCE` to avoid out of index problem, and returning one row per group with an ordered collection of [document,recommendations] pairs; maybe there's something usable there.

Comment: cool idea. not quite the same format asked for but definitely usable.